# Steema TeeChart scientific notation numbers on the chart's y-axis overflow the horizontal limits

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, teechart

Is there a way to take care of this automatically? Otherwise, is there a way to manually set the widths of these axes?

Here is a screenshot illustrating the problem:

[y-axis numbers do not fit when scientific notation is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSDn9.png)

I tried to display a Steema TeeChart with scientific notation on the y-axis. The numbers don't fit horizontally.

Comment: http://bugs.teechart.net

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A third-party chart called TeeChart from the company Steema has a bug when plotting its y-axis. Please see the attached image in my original post.